Django: Dynamic form doesn't correctly handle boolean inputs
This is a small form I have and dynamically construct:
class AddonForm(Form):

    def __init__(self, addons, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.addons = {str(addon.pk): addon for addon in addons}
        for pk, addon in self.addons.items():
            self.fields[str(pk)] = BooleanField(required=False, label=f"{addon} (x{addon.price_multiplier})")

This is how I use it:
            form = AddonForm(ItemAddonTemplate.objects.filter(item=item_template_id), request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                addons = form.cleaned_data

This is the request.POST:
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['cJS1fhGY3WqIflynGbZIh9TiRj8F9HjgoLOUL6TwWY4j4cotALGHpFDyQwjLiLMW'], '3': ['on'], '32': ['on']}>

but when I print addons I see this:
{'3': False, '30': False, '31': False, '32': False, '33': False, '34': False}

3 and 32 should be True.
This is Django 5.1 and Python 3.12.

Maybe, this is better implemented by using formsets instead:
forms.py
class AddonForm(Form):
    on = BooleanField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, addons, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Use addons qs(as list) to add and set
        properties to the form and form fields
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        addon = addons.pop(0)
        self.label = f"{addon} (x{addon.price_multiplier})"
        self.identifier = addon.id
        self.fields["on"].label = self.label

    def clean(self):
        """
        Change cleaned_data representation
        substituting the field name for addon.id
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        cleaned_data[f"{self.identifier}"] = cleaned_data.pop("on")
        return cleaned_data

views.py
def item_addons(request, item_template_id):
    addons = ItemAddonTemplate.objects.filter(item=item_template_id)

    AddonFormSet = formset_factory(AddonForm, extra=len(addons))
    formset = AddonFormSet(form_kwargs={"addons": list(addons)})

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AddonFormSet(request.POST, form_kwargs={"addons": list(addons)})
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    print(form.cleaned_data)

    return render(request, "item_addons.html", {"formset": formset})

Which "returns":
{'3': True}
{'32': True}

